# Is there a way to force GWT to parse a date with the format "1/1/9" as "January 1st, 2009" instead of "January 1st, 9"?

Tags: java, date, parsing, gwt

I am using the built-in PredefinedFormat.DATE_SHORT using en_US locale (although en_UK has the same issue) and if I enter "1/1/9" the date is parsed to Jan 1st 9. If I enter 1/1/09 it is read correctly as Jan 1st 2009. Is there some way to force GWT to do the same math it does to normalize in the latter case on the single-digit case?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html says no. And it isn't GWT doing this, it's `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: You cannot use `SimpleDateFormat` with GWT.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer is correct, the GWT class being used is DateTimeFormat which is analogous to DateFormat in Java but not the same thing.